# Dynamically update jQuery/CSS objects

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a program that creates 2 concentric circles by taking the user input for outer diameter for outer circle and circle thickness for inner circle. Occasionally, I will create a large outer diameter (50 inches) with a small thickness (2 inches) giving me the image below.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Kaevonz/wry3n0m7/121/

[image]

But when I update the size of the outer diameter to something like 20 inches, the inner diameter does not update instantly, thus giving me the image below. The inner circle from the 50 inch outer diameter is squeezed inside the new 20 inch outer diameter circle, thus making it an oval. How would I go about fixing this? I am a bit confused. I have tried changing the on('change') to on('mousemove), but that just unhides the circles the moment I move my mouse as opposed to waiting for the input from the user.

[image]

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $('.div2').hide();
    $(document).on('change', '#outer_diameter', function() {
      var $outer_diameter = parseFloat($("#outer_diameter").val()).toFixed(3);
      var $converted = ($outer_diameter * 3.75).toFixed(3);

      if ($outer_diameter > 100) {
        $("#error").text($outer_diameter + " is too big").show();
        return false;
      }

      if ($outer_diameter < 0) {
        $('#error').text('Please input positive integers').show();
        return false;
      }

      console.log($outer_diameter, $converted);
      $('.div2').css({
        height: (2 * $converted),
        width: (2 * $converted),
        top: "calc(50% - " + ($converted) + "px)",
        left: "calc(50% - " + ($converted) + "px)"
      });
      $('.div2').fadeIn(300);

      $('#error').hide();
    })




    $('.div3').hide();
    $(document).on('change', '#inner_diameter', function() {
      var $outer_diameter = parseFloat($("#outer_diameter").val()).toFixed(3);
      var $inner_diameter = parseFloat($("#inner_diameter").val()).toFixed(3);
      var $converted_2 = (($outer_diameter * 3.75) - (2 * ($inner_diameter * 3.75))).toFixed(3);

      if ($outer_diameter > 100) {
        $("#error").text($outer_diameter + " is too big").show();
        return false;
      }

      if ($inner_diameter < 0) {
        $('#error').text('Please input positive integers').show();
        return false;
      }

      if ($inner_diameter >= 0.33 * $outer_diameter) {
        $('#error').text('Wall Thickness invalid').show();
        return false;
      }


      console.log($inner_diameter, $converted_2);
      $('.div3').css({
        height: (2 * $converted_2),
        width: (2 * $converted_2),
        top: "calc(50% - " + ($converted_2) + "px)",
        left: "calc(50% - " + ($converted_2) + "px)"
      });
      $('.div3').fadeIn(300);
      $('#error').hide();
    })


    $('.div1').hide();
    $(document).on('change', '#cutter', function() {
      var $cutter = parseFloat($("#cutter").val()).toFixed(3);
      var $converted3 = ($cutter * 3.75).toFixed(3);

      if ($cutter < 0) {
        $('#error').text('Please input positive integers').show();
        return false;
      }

      if ($cutter > 72) {
        $('#error').text('Cutter too big').show();
        return false;
      }


      $('.div1').css({
        width: (2 * $converted3)
      })
      $('.div1').fadeIn(300);
      $('#error').hide();
    })

  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: start;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.elem {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.div1 {
  border-top: 3px solid #0DA8AA;
  border-left: 1px solid #0DA8AA;
  border-right: 1px solid #0DA8AA;
  height: 70px;
  background: white;
}

.div2 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.div3 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p id="error">

  </p>
  <div class="elem div1"></div>
  <div class="elem div2">
    <div class="elem div3">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="Calculations">
  <input type="number" id="cutter" placeholder="Enter Cutter O.D."> <br>
  <input type="number" id="outer_diameter" placeholder="Enter Outer Diameter"> <br>
  <input type="number" id="inner_diameter" placeholder="Enter Thickness"> <br>
  <input type="button" id="bttn" name="calculate" value="Calculate">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this will be helpful, but if you call all three input methods as function when any one of the changes it seam to work much better

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $('.div2').hide();
    $(document).on('change', '#outer_diameter', function() {
      inner_diameter()
      outer_diameter()
      cutter()
    })

    $('.div3').hide();
    $(document).on('change', '#inner_diameter', function() {
      inner_diameter()
      outer_diameter()
      cutter()
    })

    $('.div1').hide();
    $(document).on('change', '#cutter', function() {
      inner_diameter()
      outer_diameter()
      cutter()
    })

    function outer_diameter() {
      const $outer_diameter = parseFloat($("#outer_diameter").val())
        .toFixed(3);
      const $converted = ($outer_diameter * 3.75).toFixed(3);

      if ($outer_diameter > 100) {
        $("#error").text($outer_diameter + " is too big").show();
        return false;
      }

      if ($outer_diameter < 0) {
        $('#error').text('Please input positive integers').show();
        return false;
      }

      console.log($outer_diameter, $converted);
      $('.div2').css({
        height: (2 * $converted),
        width: (2 * $converted),
        top: "calc(50% - " + ($converted) + "px)",
        left: "calc(50% - " + ($converted) + "px)"
      });
      $('.div2').fadeIn(300);
      $('#error').hide();
    }

    function inner_diameter() {
      const $outer_diameter = parseFloat($("#outer_diameter").val())
        .toFixed(3);
      const $inner_diameter = parseFloat($("#inner_diameter").val())
        .toFixed(3);
      const $converted_2 = (($outer_diameter * 3.75) -
        (2 * ($inner_diameter * 3.75))).toFixed(3);

      if ($outer_diameter > 100) {
        $("#error").text($outer_diameter + " is too big").show();
        return false;
      }

      if ($inner_diameter < 0) {
        $('#error').text('Please input positive integers').show();
        return false;
      }

      if ($inner_diameter >= 0.33 * $outer_diameter) {
        $('#error').text('Wall Thickness invalid').show();
        return false;
      }

      console.log($inner_diameter, $converted_2);
      $('.div3').css({
        height: (2 * $converted_2),
        width: (2 * $converted_2),
        top: "calc(50% - " + ($converted_2) + "px)",
        left: "calc(50% - " + ($converted_2) + "px)"
      });
      $('.div3').fadeIn(300);
      $('#error').hide();
    }

    function cutter() {
      const $cutter = parseFloat($("#cutter").val()).toFixed(3);
      const $converted3 = ($cutter * 3.75).toFixed(3);

      if ($cutter < 0) {
        $('#error').text('Please input positive integers').show();
        return false;
      }

      if ($cutter > 72) {
        $('#error').text('Cutter too big').show();
        return false;
      }

      $('.div1').css({
        width: (2 * $converted3)
      })
      $('.div1').fadeIn(300);
      $('#error').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: start;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.elem {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.div1 {
  border-top: 3px solid #0DA8AA;
  border-left: 1px solid #0DA8AA;
  border-right: 1px solid #0DA8AA;
  height: 70px;
  background: white;
}

.div2 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.div3 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p id="error">

  </p>
  <div class="elem div1"></div>
  <div class="elem div2">
    <div class="elem div3">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="Calculations">
  <input type="number" value="0" id="cutter" placeholder="Enter Cutter O.D."> <br>
  <input type="number" value="0" id="outer_diameter" placeholder="Enter Outer Diameter"> <br>
  <input type="number" value="0" id="inner_diameter" placeholder="Enter Thickness"> <br>
  <input type="button" id="bttn" name="calculate" value="Calculate">
</div>
```

I hope this is helpful